# Postgres on Docker in Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, docker, docker-compose, azure-web-app-service

I try to run a Postgres Docker container in an Azure Web App.
When i try to mount a volume to the Data folder, i get the error:  FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership

my Compose script:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
    volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
```

Docker host is set to linux.

how can i get around this issue?
(if i dont, the data is lost every restart / container update)

Comment: did you follow this guide? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage

Comment: also, allow me the question if a WebApp is the best way to run postgres?! Have you thought about using the Azure-managed postgresql service?

Comment: azure-managed postgres is an option, if i cannot get it to work. Also Azure Container Service is an option, but the problem is still the same as above.

Comment: @StefanS Were you able to run it inside an Azure web app ?

Comment: @RajatArora Unfortunatly not, you need to have a Disk attached -> i ended up with using Kubernetes (AKS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, you can take a look at the Dockerfile of the image `postgres`. There is a step that changes the ownership of the directory `/var/lib/postgresql` with the command:

```
chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql
```

But when you use the persistent storage in Azure Web App, you cannot change the permission of it. So it causes the error:

> FATAL: data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership

See more details about the limitation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#you-cannot-change-permissions-on-the-home-directory-when-persisting-storageapplies-to-web-app-for-containers).

Comment: so there is no solution?

Comment: @StefanS If you use the AKS, then you can try the persist volume with the disk. It's a solution.

Comment: ok sure, this is a solution! can you point me to a startingpoint (docu or sth)?

Comment: @StefanS Yeah, you can take a look at the [persist volume with the disk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-disks-dynamic-pv).